# Ubuntu app dev language

Tags: python, application-development

I work as a java dev so I know java and I'm learning python. Is this enough for developing ubuntu desktop apps or I need more? I would like to focus on good gui builders and I know kava swing is pretty poor.

Comment: You could use swing, that'll work,too. But majority of apps written for Linux in general are in some for m of Gtk toolkit, whether it's for python or for C++ .